# Does go regexp's any charcter match newline

Tags: regex, go

Go's [re2 syntax document](//github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) says that the any character (`.`) matches any
character, including newline (`s=true`). However I wrote a simple program whose
result showed that the any character did not match newline at all. The program
can be found here:

http://play.golang.org/p/pccP52RvKS

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like most other (all?) regex engines, dot does not match newlines unless you
add the "dot all" flag `(?s)` to the regex.

I tested this using your link and it worked.

https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax

Comment: Yeah, that doc entry is just poorly phrased.  golang's own docs are written more clearly: "any character, **possibly** including newline (flag s=true)" ([ref](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/))